# "VLC is unable to open the MRL Check the log for details." Where is this log?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Receive this error on some `m3u` urls in `VLC`.

In browser urls work.

Where is this log?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.